# show/hide loading message for html table

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I show a "loading" message when clicked/checked to expand table column(s), and hide the message as soon as its expended. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/xamsw/) is demo of what I've got so far. I can make the message appear, but can't hide it once the job is done. It seems useful when I'm trying to expand a large table, and I think it would be nice to let the user know that it's working. Any help/suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#load").hide();
    $("#check").live("click", function() {
        $("#load").show();
        if ($("#check").is(":checked")) {
            $(".hidden").show();
        } else {
            $(".hidden").hide();
        }
    });
    $("#load").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need the loading message?

anyway, you could hide it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#load").hide();
    $("#check").live("click", function() {
        $("#load").show();
        if ($("#check").is(":checked")) {
            $(".hidden").show();
            $("#load").hide();
        } else {
            $(".hidden").hide();
            $("#load").hide();
        }
    });
    $("#load").hide();
});
```

Comment: sorry, i forgot to say that it seems useful when i'm trying to expand a large table, which takes several seconds to expand. i thought it would be nice to let the user know that it's working.

Answer (score 0):

this is a bit unuseful thing to create a loading text because this need only one reflows to the DOM so you actually not see the "loading.." message.

but if you want to create an ajax call wich gets the data form the server, it would be useful, but in this usuage this is unuseful

but if you insist to this, you need to create a new "thread" to detect is the table shown. for example

```
$("#link").click(function() {
$("#text").html("loading...");
$("#table").show();
window.setTimeout(function() {while(true){if($("table").is(":visible")){$("#text").html("");break;}}},0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of the page lifecycle. You don't have any blocking events in your code and there is no callback for your code to know "hey the hidden elements are shown now, hide the loading bar." Take a look at this updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xamsw/5/). Instead of a callback, I've told the code to wait .5 secs after showing or hiding before calling the method to the hide the loading message.

If you were doing something with a callback, like an AJAX post, then you could invoke this on success or fail of the request.

Comment: woops, fixed the jsfiddle link